# Finding (p,p+2) primes

Tags: r, primes, number-theory, primesense

Finding (P,P+2) Primes in R, I tried like this

```
twinPrimes(1,100)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    5
[2,]    5    7
[3,]   11   13
[4,]   17   19
[5,]   29   31
[6,]   41   43
[7,]   59   61
[8,]   71   73
```

I got the answer. But this command will work only upto finding 100000 after that also I'm getting the answer but still some error like this

```
[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 3169 rows ]
```

How to avoid this?

Comment: I would think the phrase "twin primes" would be a little more readable (at least to non-mathematicians) than `(p,p+2)` since that is, after all, the definition of twin prime.

Comment: You can set a higher value for `max.print` from `option` in this way `options(max.print = 10^9)`.

Comment: This is not an error. You just reached the limit of display.

Comment: This is only a matter of output display, and not of the data that his calculated. As mentioned above you can change the output settings. Or you can split the calculation into chunks, using , e.g., `numbers::twinPrimes(100000,200000)`.

Comment: Another option would be to store the result to a file with `write.table` and then use a text editor or a spread sheet program to look at the data.